# Deploying app on tester's device unable to save record in iCloud

Tags: ios, cloudkit

My app uses cloudkit to save records and works just fine on my phone.  I added a friend of mine's device to my 'devices' and uploaded my app to his phone.  I set iCloud dashboard to 'Production' and tried to add a record with his phone.  He can access the database, and fetch the data, but cannot save a record.  We both have iPhone 6+ and have the exact same builds of the app.  I can add records on my phone no prob.  Does Apple not allow this?

Comment: The current documentation for CloudKit says that you should be able to do ad hoc testing on provisioned devices. What have you done so far to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is this iCloud data in the public or private database?

Comment: It is in the public database

Comment: As far as troubleshooting, I have recently tried it on another person's device and it is having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in the public database, make sure the security roles (in CloudKit Dashboard) are set up such that you allow writes from authenticated users to the record type in question. Maybe you have set only yourself to have the role to write to the record type?